# How to do sth when a java method is called "for the second time" in Android Eclipse project

Tags: java, android, class

I am making a project in Android using Eclipse. In my app, I want to call a Java class for the second time.

Is there any way to keep a count of my Java class calls so as to do something on its second call?

Comment: Keep a static variable numberOfCalls in the class and have each call increment it

Comment: Something like: static numberOCalls = 0; if numberOfCalls=0 do... else if numberOfCalls = 1 do....?

Comment: Does "do sth" mean something? If so, please post complete words here on SO - this isn't Twitter and readability means a lot more than brevity. Also, how do you "call a java class"? Do you mean construct an instance of the class? Something else?

Comment: To be more precise I  want to use setContentView when a method named handleMessage inside my java class is called for the second time .

Comment: huh? Then all you need is a global int to count it, and the second time its called call setcontentview.

Comment: i post my answer , please check this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help.

I solved it following this stackoverflow link:

[How can I call a different xml on the second call of my onResume in Android Eclipse project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28966716/how-can-i-call-a-different-xml-on-the-second-call-of-my-onresume-in-android-ecli)

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution might be having a Global class holding public properties.

```
public static class GlobalProperties
{
     public Integer callNumber;
     public String lastPerson;
}
```

Or having them private with get/set methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep track of all of the calls to all instances of your Class, then you'll need something like `private static int numberOfCalls`, and increment it in each of your public methods. Otherwise, if you want an object-based counter, you need simply `private int numberOfCalls`.

Answer (score 0):

just do this :

```
class A {
     private static int countOfClassA = 0 ;
     countOfClassA ++;
     if(countOfClassA == 2)
          //do sth
}
```