# How can I call a different xml on the second call of my onResume in Android Eclipse project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, methods

I make an Android app and I want in my MainActivity.java to make a counter of my onResume method **calls** so that during onResume's:

1) first  call to `setContentView(R.layout.layout1);`

and

2) second call to `setContentView(R.layout.layout2);`

According to documentation that I seeked I should  make a static variable that will be increased for every onResume's call.

How could I implement it please?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this (rough template)

```
public class MainActivity {
    public static int contentViewCount = 0;


    public void onCreate() {   //or perhaps onStart()
          contentViewCount = 0;
    }

    public void onResume() {
        if(contentViewCount == 0) {
            //set first layout and increment the static counter
            setContentView(R.layout.layout1);
            contentViewCount++;
        } else {
            setContentView(R.layout.layout2);
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: I am obliged @gtgaxiola ! With a minor minor alteration it worked!

Answer (score 0):

you can use sharedpreference for save of counter. when onResume() called you can read counter(first line of onResume()) in sharedpreference and you can save counter last line of onResume() fuction. 
thus you can change setContentView(R.layout.layout1) according counter is double or single.